# Linear Regression completely off

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression

I am currently trying to learn scikit-learn, and for this purpose I have a simple Linear Regression for the price of Houses relative to the size in square meters.
I have done this model for a location, everything working all right, and when I tried with another dataset, the data scatters fine, but the regression/prediction is completely off! The confidence is also pretty terrible, often negative.

Here is a screenshot :

[image]

The code is the following:

```
style.use('ggplot')

dataset = pd.read_csv('/Path/Data.csv')

X = np.array(dataset[['size']])
y = np.array(dataset[['value']])

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2)

clf = LinearRegression()
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

plt.scatter(X,y)
plt.plot(X, clf.predict(X))

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

confidence = clf.score(X_test, y_test)
print confidence
```

Comment: Linear regression works well only if the data follows a linear relationship.

Comment: With the two outliers at the right end, there's no way to place a line through the majority of your points without making incredible error for the outliers. Note that linear regression assumes normally distributed residuals - therefore you calculate squared distances. Squaring is very sensitive to outliers. Besides as @hashcode55 already hinted, the trend looks at least polynomial, so might want to add quadratic terms as well.

Comment: It does follow one, especially when 0<x<1000

Comment: @cel my other linear has outliers too : http://i.imgur.com/C1TOdzO.png..
But anyways, how could I make it more forgiving for those ?

Comment: @Codemon, just draw the line you think is right and measure the distance to your outliers. I guess it would cross (1000, 6000000), so for 5000 it will be somewhere around 30million, which is very, very far away from the upper end of your plot. Which makes an error of (29million)^2, which will dominate everything.

Comment: Alright thanks, I think I will remove those 2 outliers from the dataset

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The square-error was too sensitive to the outliers. I ended up removing them since they were completely off